# How do you change the color of the output for an object in Pry?

Tags: ruby, pry

I'm building an object that is somewhat similar to nil, it's called nil_query, and is an instance of a singleton class called NilQuery.

I would like this class to display in a similar fashion to true, false, and nil when called in Pry, meaning I want it to display in it's own special color, rather than just white:

[image]

My first thought (which is how I got the results in picture above) was to just change the string from the inspect method of NilQuery to include color formatting:

```
class NilQuery
  def inspect
    "\e[36;1mnil_query\e[0m"
  end
end
```

This, of course, is a terrible idea since it changes the way that all errors are displayed to include the string of numbers defining the terminal output. So if I were to call a random undefined method in nil_query, the error would look like:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `random_method' for "\e[36;1mnil_query\e[0m":NilQuery
```

Are their any good solutions out there? I tried looking into pretty print a bit but struggled to find any good documentation on how to use it.

TL;DR - How can I change the color and format that a specific object or value shows up as in Pry?

Answer (score 1):

Pry uses [Coderay](https://github.com/rubychan/coderay) for formatting the color of the output. You might need to customize the [Ruby scanner](http://coderay.rubychan.de/doc/CodeRay/Scanners/Ruby.html) to define a new token (similar to :float, :integer, :constant etc.,) and then define the formatting/color for the [terminal](https://github.com/rubychan/coderay/blob/master/lib/coderay/encoders/terminal.rb).